# Force SSL for Heroku apps running in EU region

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, https, dns

I'm struggling to enforce an SSL connection for a rails app running on Heroku (EU region).

I've added the cert (inc Heroku SSL add-on) to a custom domain successfully (if I explicitly state https://..com it works perfectly)

But I want to redirect all http requests to a https connection.

For apps in the US regions this require pointing custom domain DNS records to .herokussl.com NOT .herokuapp.com. Docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#dns-and-domain-configuration

For apps in EU regions, custom DNS records should still point to .herokuapp.com which does not appear to enforce a SSL connection by default.

Therefore, my question is: how can I make all connections to my Heroku app running in Europe be forced to run through SSL?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

production.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
    config.force_ssl = true
end
```

This will redirect all http traffic to https

Edit: Its worth noting that this is a Rails thing rather than a heroku one.

Revision:

As this answer/question regularly gets seen and upvoted, it's also possible within a controller on a per request basis:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  force_ssl if: :ssl_configured?

  def ssl_configured?
    !Rails.env.development?
  end
end
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

FYI your question mentions `herokussl.com` which is part of the deprecated [Heroku SSL Endpoint](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint) service. Heroku now recommends using the [Heroku SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl) service:

> The SSL Endpoint add-on is only recommended if you need to support legacy browser clients which do not support SNI. Our default recommendation is to use the Heroku SSL described in [this document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl).

Also note that appname.herokuapp.com domains are already SSL-enabled and can be accessed by using https, for example, https://appname.herokuapp.com.